# Computing a "Gaussian" distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I tried to calculate the distribution (i.e. $F(x):=P(X\leq x) $) relative to the probability density $P(d\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}d\mathbf{x}$ where $\mathbf{x} = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $d\mathbf{x}$ is the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R^2},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2}))$. I want to find the distribution of the random variable $X:(x,y) \mapsto x^2 +y^2 $ defined on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2}),\mathbb{P})$. When I compute it with a standard Gaussian integral, I do it in polar coordinates and get a function depending only on the distance from the origin $R >0$. But then in what sense can it be true that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$?

Comment: It feels like $\lim_{x\to -\infty} F(x) = F(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First pass in polar coordinates obtaining

$$f_{R\Theta}(\rho,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\times \rho e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2}}=f_{\Theta}(\theta)\times f_R(\rho)$$

Where

- $f_{\Theta}(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ is the angle's density (uniform in $(0;2\pi)$)
- $f_R(\rho)$ is the radius' density: that is the density of $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
  (this is a known density: [the Rayleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution))

Now it is easy to transform it to get the density of $Z=X^2+Y^2$

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{z}{2}}\mathbb{1}_{(0;\infty)}(z)$$

That is a Negative exp distribution $Z\sim Exp(\frac{1}{2})$ or, equivalently, a $\chi_{(2)}^2$

Comment: In particular, the cdf $F$ is given by $F(x) = 1-\exp(-x/2)$ for $x\ge 0$, and $F(x) =0$ for $x<0$.